# Github App for Mac crashes upon opening

Tags: macos, github, crash, repository

Downloaded the Github for Mac app and it crashes instantly upon opening. Here is the error report:

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Received error from  name:  in binding for key path "currentActionViewModel" on : NSError { domain: GTGitErrorDomain, code: -12, description: "Failed to create reference to tracking branch from  name: refs/heads/master, shortName: master, sha: { SHA: da048479dec26b5e59ccd594bc32a4c7c8e93dc5 }, remoteName: (null), repository:  fileURL: file:///Users/johnfarmer/.Trash/first_app/", underlying error: NSError { domain: GTGitErrorDomain, code: -12, description: "'https://github.com/johnfarmernyc/first_app.git' is not a valid remote name." } }'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the repository configuration. You will have to diagnose it yourself.

I don't use Github for Mac I use Git from the command line.

Open up the Terminal.app and `cd <the path of the first_app folder>` then do a `git fetch origin` and see if that reviles anything works. You can also edit the `first_app/.git/config` file and remove references to tracking branches in hopes Github for Mac recovers again.

You can also attempt to delete the first_app repo and then use Github for Mac to re clone it again.

As a side note, You might be better off not using Github for Mac and just use Git out of the box (on the command line) it takes a little bit more of a learning curve but worth it, and there is a much larger Git community then there is a Github for Mac community.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and changing my .git/config file for the master branch from:

[branch "master"]
    remote = git@github.com:/.git

to:

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin

Fixed the problem.   GitHub support confirmed this is the correct solution.